# Replace usage of unwanted foreach with new query in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table like below

```
Employee
-------------------
id    role 
1      a
2      a
3      b
4      c
5      b
----------------------
```

The filters which I have are `ids {1,3,5} and roles {a,b}`

So I need to get the rows which have `id=1 and role=a , id=2 and role=b , id=3 and role=a, id=3 and role=b etc...`

So basically `id * roles` which I need to get from database.

The current code used in my project is like below

```
foreach (int role in roles)
                    {

                        foreach (int id in ids)
                        {
//get the data using id and role and append to a list 
}
}
```

And each iteration a db hit is happening so this makes a huge permanence issue. So I am trying to improve the code which I have and I have replaced the foreach with below code.

```
var itemsTobeDeleted = context.TableName.Where
                       (
                        item =>
                            obj.ids.Contains(item.Id) &&
                            obj.roles.Contains(item.Role)
                        ).ToList();
```

My question is is this my new query will give same result as the for each give?
If yes then what about the performance ?

Or do we have any better method for doing the same ?

Comment: use .AsNoTracking().ToList(); if you don't need the list for modification and submit it again to db. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, your second solution is more efficient!**

You use a DbContext to access your table. Apparently this table is in a database. Database management systems are extremely optimized in querying data.

However one of the slower parts of a query is the transport of the query and the selected data between your process and the DBMS. Hence it is wise to limit this.

Your foreach method will perform one query per [role, id] combination. This is very inefficient. Your 2nd method will only take one query and return only one resulting sequence. This is way more efficient.

> **Addition:**
>   Ivan Stoev showed me that the method below does not work: As opposed to an IEnumerable, IQueryable.Contains can only handle primitive types. Hence the Contains below won't work.

Therefore following doesn't work as IQueryable.
This query can be optimized a little: let your process create a sequence of the required [role, id] combinations and query the database for all `TableNames` that match this combination.

```
class RoleIdCombination
{
    public char Role {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

// let your process create the requested RoleIdCombinations:
var roleIdCombinations = CreateRoleIdCombinations(roles, ids);

// do only one query:
var result = dbContext.TableNames
    .Select(tableName => new
    {
         // for easier equality check: make a RoleIdCombination:
         RoleIdCombination = new RoleIdCombination
         {
              Role = tableName.Role,
              Id = tableName.Id,
         }
         // remember the original item
         TableName = tableName,
     })
    .Where(item => roleIdCombinations.Contains(item.RoleIdCombination));
```

So now you know that your database management system will enumerate your table only once.

Function `CreateRoleIdCombinations`:

```
IEnumerable<RoleIdCombination> CreateRoleIdCombinations(
    IEnumerable<char> roles,
    IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
     foreach (var role in roles)
     {
         foreach (var id in ids)
         {
              yield return new RoleIdCombination
              {
                  Role = role,
                  Id = id,
              };
         }
     }
}
```

For this we need (number of roles * number of ids) enumerations. I expect that this will be much smaller than the number of items in your table, after all, you won't be deleting half of your table every time, will you?

Comment: Since you are answering many questions in EF area, you should know that in-memory collection `Contains` method can be used only with primitive values. The suggested optimization will cause not supported runtime exception in EF6, and client evaluation in EF Core which will defeat the whole idea of single query.

Comment: Oh dear!  I use EF very much, even quite often `Queryable.Contains`, but never tried it with an anonymous type. You are sure that this doesn't work? Well, I'm never too old to learn! Thank you very much. The basic idea about the answer: try to make one query to fetch all data still stands, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed. Which the second OP query is perfectly doing, so the first part of the answer is correct. What about the EF6 exception, it's quite common - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bentity-framework%5D+or+%5Bentity-framework-6%5D+Contains+only+primitive+types+are+supported

Comment: No the role*id will be very smaller compared to my table size and your solution seems nice. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

If you change your collection to *set* then *Contains* costs O(1) so better performance then *List.Contains*(O(n)) is expected.

```
HashSet<int> ids= new HashSet<int>{ 1,3,5 };
```

Comment: can you just give a query which can replace my for each usign this?

Comment: Apparently his table is in a Database. He's using entity framework to access the database. SQL doesn't know a HashSet, hence he can't use it.

Comment: it's exactly what you wrote, just change ids and roles to set and it will cast less as described

Comment: still he can convert lists to hashset with totaly better performance

Comment: Mehrdad: do you propose to transfer the whole table from database to local process, then convert to hashset? It would probably be better to use a dictionary with (role, id) as key, so he can easily fetch the items to delete. But why move all items to local process, even the ones that don't have to be deleted?

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi What you are suggesting makes sense for LINQ to Objects, where the `Contains` method is really executed. But in EF (Core), a.k.a. LINQ to Entities, it will be translated to SQL `IN(val1, val2, …)` and executed inside database, so the type of the collection (`HashSet`, `List`, array etc.) doesn't really matter, because it's enumerated once when building the SQL.